# Is there any API to reply/reaction to user's message in Facebook Messaging Platform or Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

As the title suggests, is there API to send reply/reaction as Page/Messaging Platform?

[image: example image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

Comment: @CBroe of course, I read the doc - especially, this send API Ref, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/. But I couldn't find how to send reply/reaction.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, actually. Do you need to find the "entry point" where your app gets notified that the user send a message? That's what webhooks are for.

Comment: @CBroe, I want to send reply (as a Page) to user's message from API, not to listen when user reply to our message.

Comment: That's exactly what https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/ describes, so you'll need to be more specific as to what your actual problem with that is.

Comment: @CBroe when I say _reply_, I mean _quoted message_. (Is it correct word to describe? )  It looks like current Send API doesn't allow to send reply (quoted message) or reaction (emojis) to **existing** message. I guess they are using internal API.

Comment: What your screenshot shows, is the complete opposite direction - the "quoted" part is from the page, and below is the user's reply. Your bot is not in charge of the user's replies to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, I better use actual usage. Sorry for confusion in the screenshot. I'm not building the bot, I'm building something like [this](https://www.hootsuite.com/platform/engage). Human will reply message, not the bot. So, I would like to add basic features as close as Messenger. Anyways, thank you. It looks like those features are same as stickers feature.

Comment: SoeMoe, were you able to find out how to do this? Facebook API documentation doesn't include helpful information about replying to a message. Every time you search for something, it returns docs about how to respond normally. It is frustrating. I feel you.

@CBroe, he wants to use the API to generate his reply with the previous message attached. It would be like replying directly to a given message, not the conversation as a whole.

Our team is struggling too with this situation.

Comment: @yamilelias No, we can't. As a workaround, we generate image with the message that we want to reply (something like taking screenshot of the message) and send that image with text.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to reply to messages as quoted messages.
Facebook's documentation doesn't explain this, it means Facebook hasn't added this functionality for the Messages API.
I've read the documentation from Facebook about Messaging, but none of it quotes the question of replying to messages as a quoted message.